# Wordpress Shared post title text

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, share

I am managing a blog, and there is an issue with the text when the blog post is shared on facebook.
The title of the shared blog post has the title of the blog before it like this:

```
Blog Title Post Title
```

This is actually fine, but whats happening is the end of the Blog Title is right up against the Post Title like this:

```
Blog TitlePost Title
```

It looks off, I have tried editing this but I cannot see where in the .php files this is being set, and why its not adding space after the Blog Title.

Does anyone know where the is being set? or why this might be occurring?

Comment: Probably somewhere in your *header.php*

Comment: look for `wp_title()`

Comment: @diggy This is what my Title looks like in the head
     <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

Comment: Oops, I meant the filter, not the template tag: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title

Comment: @diggy Thanks, Buy I don't see the wp_title inside a filter in the header.php or functions.php

Comment: maybe some plugin working? SEO?

Comment: @diggy Its using Yoast's SEO plugin

Comment: I remember having seen a similar problem, but never got to the bottom of it. Changing `<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>` to `<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>` resolved it, I think. Give it a shot?

Comment: @diggy Thanks for the suggestions, I tried it but no luck. It didn't post the post link anymore, and now I have page not found as the post title.